# Copying a mix of files and directories with Robocopy

Tags: robocopy

If I copy files with robocopy and specify a directory name, robocopy seems to treat the directory as a file.  I have a bat file with a mix of files and directories specified.

```
set "udate=%date:~6,4%%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%"
set working="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\portal"
set live="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\live"              

robocopy    %working%   %live%  addpages.php    /e /ndl /MAXAGE:%udate%
robocopy    %working%   %live%  images  /e /ndl /MAXAGE:%udate%
```

There are more than 60 calls to robocopy in that bat file for files and for directories.  In the sample shown, addpages.php is a file, images is a directory.  Does robocopy need more information to copy directories?

Answer (score 1):

You've got it somewhat backwards, actually. Robocopy works with folders to begin with, and you're supposed to specify the source and destination folders like `robocopy %working%\images %live%\images` rather than `robocopy %working%  %live%  images`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy#Common_usage_scenarios

And I'd have to double-check this, but I'm not sure if doing recursive copying while also supplying a filespec (`addpages.php /e`) will actually do what you want.

Basically, robocopy is primarily meant for copying a large number of files and folders at once, in a single command, and isn't so much meant for copying of specific items within a directory tree.

Comment: I know that.  The standard copy command doesn't allow me to specify a date.  Before robocopy I had the xcopy command in that bat file. But it wasn't reliable for copying the files that changed since the specified date.  is there a different command that will do that?

Comment: Well... xcopy is _supposed_ to do that. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx "`/d[:mm-dd-yyyy]` : Copies source files changed on or after the specified date only. If you do not include a mm-dd-yyyy value, xcopy copies all Source files that are newer than existing Destination files. This command-line option allows you to update files that have changed."

Comment: That is, xcopy is technically supposed to do what you want, so you may want to check to see if the problem lies in the arguments you've been supplying to xcopy (for instance, see if you're using `/d` by itself rather than with a specific date, and if not try that, and see if `/h` and/or `/r` are needed if you aren't using them), and then if the problem isn't there, check whether or not the `Date Modified` metadata of the files in question is getting updated properly when they're modified.